# What does this particular phrase mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I asked my friend how his exam went and he said
"Math bent over for me"

What does it mean? Or is it some wrong phrasing? Either way, what is he trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

This is heavy slang. "To bend over" is a sexual allusion (which I leave to your imagination). In slang usage, it is used to convey the ideas of [dominance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dominance) and [submission](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/submission). Your friend is saying that he [*dominated*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dominate) his math exam. In other words, he thinks he did very well.